# Wait for enough data available from the pipe while polling

Tags: linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, pipe, ipc

Consider a multi-process application where parent process communicates with it's children via pipes. The parent `poll()`s children: sends chunks of data and receives the processed results and processing statuses via separate pipes. Children may operate only on a set of 'whole' chunks of data.
How can child processes wait for enough ('whole chunk') data available in the pipe? Is there any limit on the amount of data sent to the pipe but not yet read from it? What happens on the sending side if the pipe becomes 'clogged'?

Comment: Is it a general question, or you have a specific OS/platform in your mind?

Comment: This is Linux-based platform application.